# Why is my subprocess.communicate() missing part of the output?

Tags: python, subprocess

Trying to catch stderr of my subprocess.Popen and there's situation i can't understand.

```
    pmrep = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf8')
    out, err = pmrep.communicate()
```

"out" variable value is:

```
'\nInformatica(r) PMREP, version [10.1.1 HotFix2], build [1507.1025], Windows 32-bit\nCopyright (c) 1993-2017 Informatica LLC. All Rights Reserved.\nSee patents at https://www.informatica.com/legal/patents.html.\n\n\nInvoked at Tue Jan 26 17:57:08 2021\n\n01/26/2021 17:57:08 **** Importing Workflow: WF_CLIENT2MANAGER_SHIST ...\n'
```

"err" value is empty string.
Exitcode is 6 (something is not ok)

If i change stderr output to subprocess.STDOUT i get the same text in "out" and "err" is None.

However, if i remove stdout-stderr redirection i get "out" and "err" set to None BUT terminal window in my Visual Studio Code catches the following (take notice of last two ERROR lines):

```
Informatica(r) PMREP, version [10.1.1 HotFix2], build [1507.1025], Windows 32-bit
Copyright (c) 1993-2017 Informatica LLC. All Rights Reserved.
See patents at https://www.informatica.com/legal/patents.html.


Invoked at Tue Jan 26 18:02:41 2021

01/26/2021 18:02:41 **** Importing Workflow: WF_CLIENT2MANAGER_SHIST ...
ERROR: Unexpected condition at file:[..\..\..\common\reposit\tsesscfg.cpp] line:[1073]. Application terminating. Contact Informatica Technical Support for assistance.
ERROR: Unexpected condition at file:[..\..\..\common\reposit\tsesscfg.cpp] line:[1073]. Application terminating. Contact Informatica Technical Support for assistance.
```

Why can't i catch those two error lines in stdout or stderr (out and err variables)?
They are for sure coming from my subprocess (since they're connected to the command i'm invoking) and that's literally all the code that is executed (i have a breakpoint right after "pmrep.communicate()").

I'm kind of stuck, any help appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps `command` is not writing to either stdout or to stderr. On Windows, one can write to `'CON'`, e.g., `open('CON', 'w').write('foo\n')` and the text is printed on the terminal but not to stdout.

Comment: Please post an actual MCVE. For example, replace your C++ program with a 2-line bash or batch script that echoes to the two streams.